# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined while using jquery form validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form-validator

I'm using `jquery` form validation plugin to validate my form, after all validations are successful, then i call the submit function. But an error **"Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"** using `jquery` form validation plugin is occurring while applying regex to the fields, Above field is `prefilled` so i think it is because of that. Below is the Image of error.

[image: Here is error Image]

Below is my code for that:-

```
<form id="email-form">
   <input type="text" class="text-field-3 w-input" maxlength="256" autofocus="true" name="first-name" data-name="first-name"
     placeholder="First Name" id="first-name-2">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#email-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }).validate({ // initialize the plugin
     rules: {
       "first-name": {
         required: true,
         regex: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/i
       }
     }
   })
</script>
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: you should have to include your validate plugins before this document ready code.

Comment: I included it. But not working.

Comment: Make sure you are including Javascript/Jquery lib in proper order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include regex function, just do like below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  (function($,W,D){
    var JQUERY4U = {};
    JQUERY4U.UTIL = {
     setupFormValidation: function(){
        $.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
        return regexpr.test(value);
     }); 

 $('#email-form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 }).validate({ // initialize the plugin
   rules: {
   "first-name": {
      required: true,
      regex: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/i
    }
  }
 })
}
}
$(D).ready(function($) {
    JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
});
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

**Please ignore indentation of code.**

Answer (score 1):

Add a function as follows to support regex: 'expression':

```js
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function (value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
   "Please check your input."
);
```